# Android Parse: Can't update local user

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a custom boolean field called Approved in my custom ParseUser object. We change this field from false to true via a web app. According to the documentation, I should be able to update currentUser after changing the flag with fetchInBackground(), like this:

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
        Log.v("qwer", "fetched User: " + ((CustomUser)parseObject).isApproved());
    }
});
```

But even though the approved flag has been set to true, the result coming back from the server is always false. Unless I logout and login again, at which point currentUser and the respective field is synced with the server.

Why doesn't fetchInBackground() work for the local user, and if I'm using it incorrectly, how do I update the currentUser.

Comment: Are you sure you can just cast parseObject to a CustomUser?

Comment: Yeah, I extended the ParseUser class. Technically I could just have defined the callback type as CustomUser but I just cast it for clarity in this example.

Comment: It's been awhile since using Parse, but don't you need to do `pinInBackground` to save to the local datastore?

Comment: @cricket_007 That's a good question, another user submitted a similar answer below which I commented on.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this](https://parse.com/questions/how-do-i-store-parseobject-in-both-local-datastore-and-parse-cloud) link, the point is to use `pinInBackground` and also enable local datastore with `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(yourContext);` in your `Application` class.

---

Update:

Not sure if this will help you, but I do have a similar situation with you:

I do a typical `user.put("userVerified", true);` then `user.saveInBackground` to save a boolean that indicates whether user has been verified, then in the next activity I use `user.getBoolean("userVerified")` to retrieve the flag...Would this be something you might consider?

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with pinning. I don't understand why I would have to pin the currentUser object, it exists for the duration of my session. I just want to update the currentUser, not manage another layer of local data.

Comment: Hmm...take a look at my updated answer, not sure if it answers your question but might be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This won't quite work since we're updating the flag via a webapp and not client-side. Should I use saveInBackground() client side, currentUser would sync itself (if I'm remembering correctly) and everything would be fine.